# How to tell if curl times out on the client or server?

Tags: php, curl

I'm connecting to a resource using curl and php (using GET to fetch some data). From time to time the operation fails. The error I see is '*Operation timed out after 20001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received*'. I understand that the operation timed out, but how can I check if that happens on the client or the server side? I think it might be possible that my server times out before we reach the destination.

Here's the data from curl

```
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 20.001804
[namelookup_time] => 0.000198
[connect_time] => 0.016918
[pretransfer_time] => 0.059324
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => 0
[starttransfer_time] => 0
[redirect_time] => 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server decides to time out it sends a response with status 408. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/408.

If you don't received this response status, then it is the client who is tired of waiting.

Comment: I see. So if I see [http_code] => 0 in the log, that means it timed out on the client?

Comment: I would assume so, yes. But please note that if the client says "timeout", then it is the server which did not respond - or which failed to send its response back to the client.